# creating a simple one-way hash

Tags: javascript, hash, cryptography, hashmap

Are there any standard hash functions/methods that maps an arbitrary 9 digit integer into another (unique) 9 digit integer, such that it is somewhat difficult to map back (without using brute force).

Hashes should not collide, so every output `1 ≤ y < 10^9` needs to be mapped from one and only one input value in `1 ≤ x < 10^9`.

Comment: If you have a gigabyte of storage at your disposal, you could create a one time pad, by doing a fischer yates shuffle on the ordered numbers from 1-10^9. Not exactly what you are asking for, but I think it is extremely unlikely you will find a hashing function with the features you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you describe is really what *Format-Preserving Encryption* aims to solve.

One standard is [currently being worked out](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/BCM/documents/proposedmodes/ffx/ffx-spec.pdf) by NIST: the new FFX mode of encryption for block ciphers.

It may be more complex than what you expected though. I cannot find any implementation in Javascript, but some examples exist in other languages: [here](https://bitbucket.org/cmcqueen1975/crypto/src/768647869449/format-preserving-encryption.py) (Python) or [here](http://botan.randombit.net/fpe.html) (C++).

Answer (score 1):

You are requiring a non-colliding hash function with only about 30 bits. That's going to be a tall order for any hash function. Actually, what you need is not a Pseudo Random Function such as a hash but a Pseudo Random Permutation.

You could use an encryption function for this, but you would obviously need to keep the key secret. Furthermore, encryption functions normally bits as input and output, and `10^9` is not likely to use an exact number of bits. So if you are going for such an option you may have to use format preserving encryption.

You may also use any other function that is a PRP within the group 0..10^9-1 (after decrementing the value with 1), but if an attacker finds out what parameters you are using then it becomes really simple to revert back to the original. An example would be a multiplication with a number that is relatively prime with 10^9-1, modulo 10^9-1.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/LmAWH/) is what i can come up with:

```
var used = {};

var hash = function (num) {
    num = md5(num);
    if (used[num] !== undefined) {
        return used[num];
    } else {
        var newNum;
        do {
            newNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000000) + 1;
        } while (contains(newNum))
        used[num] = newNum;
        return newNum;
    }
};

var contains = function (num) {
    for (var i in used) {
        if (used[i] === num) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};

var md5 = function (num) {
    //method that return an md5 (or any other) hash
};
```

I should note however that it will run into problems when you try to hash a lot of different numbers because the `do..while` will produce random numbers and compare them with already generated numbers. If you have already generated a lot of numbers it will get more and more unlikely to find the remaining ones.

Comment: Somehow I think that is not the only trouble you are going to run into if you use above code. If you input the same number, how are you sure you generate the same hash with that random in it?

Comment: Yeah you're right. When I think about it, this is not really what the OP was looking for. It will generate the same hash only in the same session but if you reload the page it will generate new, different hashes.